# struct definition in header file: type defaults to 'int'

Tags: c, struct, kernel, global-variables, extern

I've a structure declaration and definition in header file `header.h` as:

```
#include <linux/slab.h>

struct hello{
    int a;
    char b;
};

extern struct hello *hello;
```

In file1.c I've:

```
#include<header.h>

struct hello *hello;
hello=kmalloc(sizeof(struct hello), __GFP_REPEAT);
kfree(hello);    //just to check later if 'hello' -
hello=NULL;      //-is initialized or not.
```

In file2.c I've:

```
#include<header.h>
```

The struct variable `hello` is used in `file1.c` and `file2.c`.

But while compiling I get an error:

```
file1.c:3:1 error: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'hello' [-Werror=implicit-int]
file1.c:4:1 error: conflicting types for 'hello'
file1.c:3:16 note: previous declaration of 'hello' was here 
 extern struct hello *hello;
```

I've never used variable definition in header file. Searched online and got this from few sources. Unable to find what is wrong. A lot of other errors are there after this which originates due to the mentioned error.

## Edited to include the proper codes.

Comment: naming the variable the same as the struct is a very bad programming practice and will result is massive errors when performing maintenance some 6 months (or years) from now.  Even this early, you are getting burned from making this naming error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this:

```
hello=kmalloc(sizeof(struct hello), __GFP_REPEAT);
```

really at file-level scope like that? You can't have code like that outside a function in C, but I would expect a different error message.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve the above thing using something-else. And yes, I've never used `kmalloc` outside a function before. This is the first time I'm trying.

Comment: That is ... interesting reasoning, since what you've done isn't valid, and thus doesn't achieve *anything*. :) What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `hello` is actually a linked list (sorry for not mentioning that too). Whenever I try to assign something to `hello`, I check `if(hello==NULL)` then create 2 nodes for the linked list including the root node. `else` create only one node and add it to the linked list.

Comment: @RatDon I wasn't very clear, sorry. I'll try again: what are you trying to achieve *by putting that code outside of any function*? Is this some kind of initialization?

Comment: C won't allow it just because you are trying it *for the first time* ;-) Not sure if you are ready to play with kernel code before fully grasping basics of C.

Comment: @BlueMoon and @ unwind Sorry. Since the mentioned error pointer was at somewhere-else. my concentration was there only. moved the codes inside a function. It's working fine. 
To be true, i'm just modifying an existing kernel module and hence I don't know which function is called first as all the functions are being called using arguments to a command. so i thought of making the initialization global.
Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` and the compiler assumes `int` as default return value for `malloc()`.

The default `implicit int` has been removed since C99. In any case, you should always include necessary hesders to get correct prototypes.

Comment: I've just mentioned a sample code regarding my problem. Rest all header files are there. And the whole code is in kernel. So instead of `malloc()`, I'm using `kmalloc()`.

Comment: @RatDon Do you expect us to magically know things you're not including in your question?

Comment: You can't use user space headers in kernel code. If it's just an example, I assume you haven't included `<linux/slab.h>` which has prototype for `kmalloc()`.

Comment: @BlueMoon Updated the question with the exact sample of my code.

Comment: @unwind sorry! my mistake. I thought that is not relevant to this error. Any way. Updated my question. Thanks for that.

Comment: And you are still getting the *same* errors after including the header? Your errors and code you posted doesn't seem to match.

Comment: @BlueMoon Header files were there only as I was using `kmalloc()` before inserting this code. and yes. the error is coming like this only.

Comment: You can't have *statements* (except declarations) outside of a function's body. Wrap your code in a function.